Identify the special function with this sum and integral form
There is a multivariate generalization of the Bessel function that has both a sum and integral form. Both are functions of a vector $\mathbf{0}\leq\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, with parameters defined by an $K\times n$-dimensional integer matrix $\mathbf{H}$ and $K$-dim integer vector $\mathbf{v}$.
The sum is over all non-negative $n$-dimensional integer vectors $\mathbf{m}$ that satisfy the constraint $\mathbf{Hm}=\mathbf{v}$,
$$
f_{\mathbf{H},\mathbf{v}}(\mathbf{\alpha})=\sum_{\mathbf{m},\mathbf{H}\mathbf{m}=\mathbf{v}}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{x_j^{m_{j}}}{m_{j}!}
$$
Note the sum can be finite or infinite in general.
The integral form is over the torus $U(1)^K$, reminiscent of integral form of the Bessel function,
$$
f_{\mathbf{H},\mathbf{v}}(\mathbf{\alpha})=\int \frac{d^{K}\mathbf{\phi}}{(2\pi)^K} e^{-i\mathbf{\phi}\cdot\mathbf{v}}\exp\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j \prod_{k=1}^K e^{i\phi_{k}H_{kj}}\right).
$$
I can show these are equal, but I don't know how to solve this, or of any relation to multivariate special functions.
The sum looks related to a projected or restricted Poisson distribution, but can also reduce to the multinomial distribution when $\mathbf{H}=(1,1,\cdots,1)$. Any pointers are appreciated.

These are two forms of the $\mathbf{H}$-hypergeometric function. See here and here.
